# Many sprites need to load on mobile devices in unity3D

Tags: mobile, unity-game-engine, sprite, 2d-games, atlas

My 2D game has 3 characters which each character has 7 types of animation that is contained to many frames. Those are around 1050 frames (sprites) for all 3 characters animations. I make atlas by these sprites but right now it is around 60 2048x2048 atlases with compressed format.

So on some devices which I've tested, The game is not loaded but on some other devices it is. I think it's because of too many atlases which they can't load on these mobile devices RAM.

I've tried to make these frames as small as possible and put them in atlas but as I said before the number of atlases is 60 and I can't reduce number of frames or size of them more than this.

What do you think guys and what can I do ?

Comment: Do you need ALL frames all the time? Otherwise, just load the currently needed atlas + whatever you need for the next frew rendering frames and then aggresively purge loaded frames when you don't need them anymore.

Comment: Actually Unity3D do it automatically. So I don't need to control rendering atlases.

Answer (score 1):

**There is a limitation in mobile devices for how many images can load in ram**. This is a bad idea to import your sprite with 2048*2048 dimension and then compress them to something like 512*512. You have to reduce the size of those sprite in an image editor program and then you can join 16 512*512 images and make a 2048*2048 sprite. Now you just load 1 image in mobile ram instead of 16 images.

Comment: These atlases are 2048x2048. I merge some sprites in one 2048x2048 image :)